# How to prove the following problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}$ converges. Prove that:
$$
n\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}a_{k}\to0
$$
Wish someone can provide me with some clue about this problem.

Comment: Is there any condition for $a_n$, such as nonnegativity or absolute convergence?

Comment: The statement is not true if we take $a_n = -1$ for all $n$.

Comment: @bellcircle No no such conditions are given.

Comment: @5xum Well if $a_n=-1$ the sequence is not convergent

Comment: @5xum Well if $a_n=-1$ the sequence is not convergent

Comment: @DiaryofNewton I know. But it's also $<\infty$, is it not?

Comment: it does not make sense if $a_n<0$. i think there is a missing condition

Comment: @DiaryofNewton What is the meaning of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n<\infty$ if $a_n$'s are not necessarily non-negative?

Comment: It’s convergent.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb It means that the series converges.

Comment: ASBP - Apply Summation By Parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nonnegativity is not required.

Suppose the series $\sum k a_k$ converges and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n k a_k  = S$$

Summing by parts we get

$$n \sum_{k=n}^m a_k = n \sum_{k=n}^m ka_k \frac{1}{k} = n \left[\frac{S_m}{m} - \frac{S_{n-1}}{n} + \sum_{k=n}^mS_k\left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1} \right)\right]$$

The last sum on the RHS converges as $m \to \infty$ since the summand is $\mathcal{O}(k^{-2})$.  Taking the limit of both sides as $m \to \infty$ and noting that $S_m/m \to 0$ we get

$$n \sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k = - S_{n-1} + n\sum_{k=n}^\infty S_k\left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1} \right)$$

For any $\epsilon> 0$ and all sufficiently large $n$ we have for $k \geqslant n$,

$$S- \epsilon \leqslant  S_k \leqslant S + \epsilon,$$

and

$$-S_{n-1} +n (S- \epsilon)\sum_{k=n}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1} \right) \leqslant n\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k \leqslant -S_{n-1} +n (S+ \epsilon)\sum_{k=n}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1} \right) $$

Noting the telescoping sum converging to $1/n$, it follows that

$$-S_{n-1} + S - \epsilon\ \leqslant n\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k \leqslant -S_{n-1} + S+ \epsilon,$$

whence,

$$-\epsilon \leqslant \liminf_{n \to \infty}\,\, n\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k\leqslant \limsup_{n \to \infty}\,\,n\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k \leqslant \epsilon$$

Since $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily close to $0$ we must have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k = 0$$

Comment: Wow thanks, I think that's right

Comment: @DiaryofNewton: You're welcome.  This is a nice question as it illustrates a combination of several useful techniques.